# Array of ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I was recently given the undertaking of expediting the speed of one of my company's large(ish) macros. I've done quite a decent job so far, as the last writer more or less used the record feature (making some of the code extraneous), which leads me to these formatting conditions:

```
With Range("AH10:AP10").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With
With Range("AH17:AP17").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With
With Range("AH24:AP24").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With
With Range("AH34:AP34").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With
With Range("AH42:AP42").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With
```

My question then becomes, why does this not work in its place?

```
Dim RangeArr(5) As Variant
RangeArr(0) = Range("AH10:AP10")
RangeArr(1) = Range("AH17:AP17")
RangeArr(2) = Range("AH24:AP24")
RangeArr(3) = Range("AH34:AP34")
RangeArr(4) = Range("AH42:AP42")

For i = 0 To 4
With RangeArr(i).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With
Next
```

I get a run-time error 424, object required for the loop, but using msgbox printing the array is valued as such. I'm assuming it's the array that's written incorrectly, I just can't find out how to fix it. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have made a good start!  You need an array of ranges:

```
Sub human()
    Dim RangeArr(0 To 4) As Range
    Set RangeArr(0) = Range("AH10:AP10")
    Set RangeArr(1) = Range("AH17:AP17")
    Set RangeArr(2) = Range("AH24:AP24")
    Set RangeArr(3) = Range("AH34:AP34")
    Set RangeArr(4) = Range("AH42:AP42")

    For I = 0 To 4
    With RangeArr(I).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Gary's Student. @Joe Laviano - it may seem like the answer is the same as your code, but defining RangeArr as Range and using Set does make a difference.

Comment: An array of Ranges requires syntax similar to a single range.

Comment: Works like a charm! I'll admit the only VBA I know is more or less browsing on these forums, so I can function I just miss alot of the fundamentals. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: +1, and as an alternate, instead of looping through an array of ranges, you could perform the operation on a single range group: `With Range("AH10:AP10,AH17:AP17,AH24:AP24,AH34:AP34,AH42:AP42").Interior`